# Dynamic html/javascript drop down list populated from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I think I must be missing something very simple here (and apologies if I am).

I have a html doc with javescript in it, and in that html doc, I want to create a dropdown list whose values are automtically populated from the result of a mysql query.

I'm guessing that I need to run a php script to get the info from the database, but then how to get that info into the dropdown is a mystery to me.

Please could someone point me in the wright direction - perhaps an example where someone has already done this.

I can't just write the dropdown in PHP as it would mean going away from the html page that I have everything else on.

Many thanks,

Rob.

Comment: "I can't just write the dropdown in PHP as it would mean going away from the html page that I have everything else on." I'm sorry, but can you explain this a little further? There should be no reason why your php code has to take you away from the html page on which it lives. I claim you certainly can populate your dropdown using php (which seems a lot simpler than doing it with JavaScript).

Comment: ..It's all VERY messy. I've written (read cobbled together) a html page, with lots of Javascript functions that somehow do what they're supposed to - which is generate a google map using the google maps API. What I'm trying to do, is generate the dropdown on that same page so that when a user picks an item from the dynamically created dropdown list, it kicks off a javascript function to change the map with the new information (from the dropdown), and that html page is called as a wrapped item from my Joomla! CMS.  So, as I said, it's all VERY VERY messy, and I'm no programmer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a very broad question, so I can give you a broad answer. Simple guidelines.

You have some options:

**Put PHP in the HTML**

- rename your .html to .php or change your webserver settings (through .htaccess probably if you use Apache) to let php process .html files
- put something like this into the HTML code at the appropriate place:

*xy.php/html*

```
<select name="fos">
<?php
  //php code to get data from mysql
  //foreach/while to iterate through elements
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
  //end of foreach/while
?>
</select>
```

**Use Ajax to load data**

- leave the HTML as it is now
- write a PHP script to output the dropdown
- write Javascript to get the output of the PHP script with Ajax, then insert it to the DOM in the appropriate place
- the downside is that people without JS won't see the dropdown

**EDIT: or Take the approach that *Haza* suggested**

Whichever you choose, I've given you the keywords to search for or ask further questions on

Comment: Thanks, I think that I need to use the 2nd approach (the rest of the page can't be viewed without javascript enabled anyway, so that's fine). Could you point me to any examples where I can crib from the code - I'm muddling my way through this and I learn more by example. I'm going through some tutorials at the moment, but don't really understand the use of the DOM.  I can easily call a .php from the html doc in a javascript function, but its the getting the info back into the javascript / html and building the dropdown from that php result that I'm stuck on.  Thanks again. Rob.

Comment: To "call" the PHP, you use Ajax (XMLHttpRequest object), with that you can easily retrieve the output of the PHP script (which will be the HTML for the dropdown). Then you can insert it even using `innerHTML`. Learn about the techniques for example here: http://www.ajaxtutorial.net/. You could also use jQuery, it helps a lot with Ajax.

Comment: Also if you are satisfied with any of the answers here, don't forget to accept the one you like most with the tickmark.

Comment: Ok, so this is how far I've now got (and thanks for all the help so far!). I have a .php which generates the dropdown just as I want it. The last bit of the code looks as below.
` <select name="Title">
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
   <option value = <?=$row['id']?> > <?=$row['title']?> </option>     `  The Bit I'm stick with now, is what I need to put in the html / javascript page to pull this dropdown in. Apologies for being thick.

Comment: I guess this deserves it's own question. Describe everything you did so far, and someone will help you with it. For now I can say, all you have to do is write a Javascript function that calls the php and gets its output (you do this with Ajax). And then you can insert it to the HTML (Javascript DOM insertion).

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about some fancy Javascript dropdown menu list, there is two part :

- Get the data you need to display to the user, and print them in the html in as known strcture (usually some `<ul><li>` ...). This will just create a list, wich is what a menu should generally be.
- Transform this simple list into you dropdown menu using some javascript.

So, first you need to find in your code wich part of it is the simple list, add your data into it using the same structure, and them, your js script will be able to transform it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of web development. My dear first try to do some search.
Here is some code through which you can accomplish your task

```
<select name='myselect'>
<?php
$q="select * from $table";
$rs=mysql_query($q);
if($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs))
{
  while($rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs))
  { 
   echo("<option value='$rd->id'>$rd->name</option>");
  }
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: @bazmegakapa Thanks man. Can you please guide me how can I accomplish this myself in future/

Comment: write your code, highlight it and use the `{}` button on the editor's toolbar or Ctrl+K. No need to escape `<` or add `pre` tag.