# Calling a javascript function from a php dropdown, loaded with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Now if the heading isn't enough to put you off, then you probably know the answer to this question.

And first of all, thank you to everyone who's been offering help to me over the last couple of questions, but a special thanks to Bazmegakapa for all his help.

Here's the final problem (for now):

I have a dropdown box written in PHP that populates itself from a MySQL database.
The dropdown box is pulled into my HTML / Javasccript page using jQuery.load
What I now need to happen is that when someone selects one of the options from the dropdown, it calls a javascript function, passing it the value of the selected item from the dropdown.

Can't work out how to do this - and it's probably very simple (but so am I)

Thanks all!

Rob.

Comment: Previous question (to give you some guidelines about existing code): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341792/how-to-insert-a-php-dropdown-in-a-html-javascript-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` is inserted through `.load()`, so you have to define a callback to run when the `.load()` operation is complete and successful. You can do it like this ([jQuery load() doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)):

```
$('#i_want_my_select_here').load('/temp/select.php', function () { //callback
  $('select', this).change(function () { //catch onchange event of select
    //call your function here, pass the selected value
    start($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I promise, this really is the last bit - there is also another variable that has been defined just before the jQuery, and I need to pass that value to the function too. I tried just doing    `code` start($(this).val(), user); `code` (user is the variable) but that didn't work. I also tried $user (just for the heck of it) but that didn't work either.

Comment: Depends on where was `user` defined, in which scope. Maybe it is not available in that scope.

Comment: litterally, on the line above the ` $('#i_want...... ` line, it reads ` var user = 'some user' `

Comment: Should work then... Hard to guess given this many info. Either read about variable scopes, or if you can't get it, post a question with code details.

Answer (score 3):

Quick working example for doing something on a selectbox with its value

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="1">foo</option>
   <option value="2">bar</option>
   <option value="3">bla</option>
   <option value="4">test</option>
</select>

<script>

    function start(value) {
       //do something with the value
    }

   $('#dropdown').change(function() {

    //do something with this value like calling a function etc.

  //$(this).val() returns the value of the selected element
     start($(this).val());
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I probably should have mentioned that I have only got this far by trial and error, and I've only been 'playing' with this sort of stuff for about 8 weeks, so please forgive the stupidity of this, but if I said that I want to call an existing function called 'start' and pass it the value of the selected item, please can you tell me what the code should look like.  Thanks. Rob.

Comment: I've edited my code to reflect your requirements. Just define a start function which accepts 1 parameter and call it in the change event function

Comment: Thanks for that Alex. Helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

All you need in Javascript (not jQuery in particular) is an onclick event for the dropdown where you call a function with `this.value` as the parameter.